# remove after pseudo element in part of a text

Tags: css

I have a H1 title with an ::after element to put a highlight on it, and I want to remove it in part of the title (or, better, add it only in a part of it).

There is my title : [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLJoc.png)

I tried to use a span class to add it, or to remove, but everytime it's doing it on the whole title.

Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 103%;
  height: 0;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 16px solid orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bonjour, c'est moi</h1>
```

I tried to remove the after and create a span class like "line" which should add on the span.line::after what to put the highlight, and tried with a "rm-line" class which is replacing current by "content: none;" but that's not working too.

What is the best solution ?

Render I want is this one :
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mktTk.png)

Comment: Sure, it's done. But the HTML is only a basic H1. Not sure than can help?

Comment: If you have access to the markup, I suggest you insert a wrapper element surrounding the part you want to underline and then apply the border to this wrapper element instead of the whole `<h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a H1 title with an ::after element to put a highlight on it, and I want to remove it in part of the title (or, better, add it only in a part of it).

Probably *don't* use a pseudo-element for your highlighting at all.

Instead, style your child `<span>` element differently from your parent `<h1>` element.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.main-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-heading">Bonjour, c'est <span class="highlight">moi</span></h1>
```

Comment: Ok, in your case that works fine but <span> causes problems with border-bottom in my case. Using <em> like the next answer should be a good solution, seems to work.

Comment: No worries. Note that _phrasing elements_ like `<span>` and `<em>` present differently only so far as their applied CSS Rules direct them to.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a child element containing the content you want to emphasize, then apply the effect to this child element instead.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
h1 em {
  position: relative;
}
h1 em::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 103%;
  height: 0;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 16px solid orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bonjour, <em>c'est moi</em></h1>
```

Comment: Nice !! <em> Should work, istead of <span> which is designing the entire line.